# JRuby access char

Tags: char, jruby, type-conversion

I'm trying to use a method from a Java class whose parameter type is `char`, but I can't seem to get it to work. If I try constructing a new instance of `java.lang.Character`, it throws the error:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (TypeError) cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.java.proxies.ConcreteJavaProxy to char
...[stacktrace; not important]...
```

When I try to create a new instance of `Java::char` using `Java::char.java_class.new(my_number)`, it raises `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Well, in the jirb, it gives me this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for class char:Java::JavaClass
```

or if I use `Java::char.to_java.new(my_number)`, it gives the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for #<Class:0x1556b277f>
```

I'm really stuck on what to do; all I need is to get a java character somehow that can be passed through the type system successfully. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out; apparently Jruby will coerce Ruby Fixnums into Java Characters if needed. Problem solved.